# alternating default value for new field in mysql database

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table of people, around 50K+ records. I need to add a new field 'given_number' to this table that defaults to an alternating 1, 2 or 3.

e.g.

```
id 1 - given_number = 1
id 2 - given_number = 2
id 3 - given_number = 3
id 4 - given_number = 1
id 5 - given_number = 2
id 6 - given_number = 3
id 7 - given_number = 1
id 8 - given_number = 2
id 9 - given_number = 3
```

What's the best way of doing this?

Comment: Create the field and assign `MOD(id - 1, 3) + 1` to it

Comment: Does the number have to be accurately assigned? What happens when a row is deleted? Can it be done at query time rather than insert time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Being given_number always a calculation you can make from id (id plus 1 modulo 3 plus 1), I think you don't need to actually **have** that field in the table, but ask for that calculation whenever you need it, and name that calculation given_number:

```
SELECT (id+1)%3+1 AS given_number, ... FROM ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to add column first then by using sql you need to set the value for newly added field

Answer (score 0):

I don't think i have a best solution but may be you can try this:

Add column with default set to 1
then update and increment all rows by 1 whose Id is divisible by 2
in same way increment all rows by whose id is divisible by 3.